# Oracle Datapump dbms_datapump API - How to mask/hide encryption_password parameter

Tags: plsql, datapump

I am trying to run an encrypted datapump export using the following options, please let me know how can we hide / mask the ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD which need to be provided in clear text , we don't use TDE or keystore wallet.

```
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name =>'ENCRYPTION', value => 'ALL');
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name =>'ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD', value => 'xxxxxxxxx');
```

Is it possible to declare a variable like V_PASSWORD and pull the ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in a table and access it via the code below

```
declare
  v_pass varchar2(100);
  ...
begin
  select password
  into   v_pass
  from   my_secure_table
  where  key = 'DATA_PUMP_PASSWORD';

  dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, 
    name =>'ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD', 
    value => v_pass);
  
  ...
end;
```

but ultimately of course, you have really just shifted the key security problem to somewhere else, so you'd want to make sure you have strict controls over that table.